# Executable path keyword is not working for me

Tags: testing, driver, robotframework

I am integrating my Robot framework scripts with Jenkins. Previously i used Python version path for drivers, It was working fine.but now we need to keep the drivers in project location and we need to give that path into the executable path keyword. i tried with absolute path and relative path, but it is not working.Please find the below script for your reference. I kept my drivers in same folder wherever this file available. So , by default this ${CURDIR} is returning current file directory.

## Below error i am getting inside of executable path

```
    *** Settings ***
Library      SeleniumLibrary
Variables    ../Resources/PageObjects/Login_Dashboard_TestData.py
Variables    ../Resources/PageObjects/Login_Dashboard_locators.py

*** Keywords ***
Start Browser
    [Arguments]                ${url}
    Set Global Variable  ${testsRootFolder}  ${CURDIR}
    log        ${testsRootFolder}
    ${chrome_path}      Catenate   SEPARATOR=       ${CURDIR}          \\     chromedriver.exe
    log     ${chrome_path}
    create webdriver           ${Browser}       executable_path='${chrome_path}'
    ${driver}=                 Open Browser    ${url}       ${Browser}
    Set Global Variable        ${driver}
    Maximize Browser Window
```

I am getting below error.

Setup failed:
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

In above script issue with "Chrome" keyword. Instead of capital C m using small c.
But now m facing an issue with replace string. Need to replace single slash with double slash. I tried using below script. But it is giving invalid syntax error.

```
  ${chrome_path}      Catenate   SEPARATOR=      ${EXECDIR}          \\     chromedriver.exe
log     ${chrome_path}
${chrome_path}=       Evaluate    ${chrome_path}.replace('\\','\\\\')

log     ${chrome_path}
Create Webdriver     ${Browser}   executable_path=${chrome_path}
Go To    ${url}
```

Comment: I don't know if it's the only problem, but you shouldn't have quotes around `${chrome_path}` Also, please let us know which line is throwing that error.

Comment: Hi Bryan, I tried everything with quotes and without quotes. Still same error.I am getting error in "Create webdriver" Key word.

Comment: Hi Bryan, I updated the requirement, Can u please look into this issue. I am trying to replace single slash with double slash in driver path as it is not accepting single slash.

Answer (score 0):

Issue resolved. I updated the script from Evaluate string to Replace String. Working fine now.

```
    *** Settings ***
Library      SeleniumLibrary
Variables    ../Resources/PageObjects/Login_Dashboard_TestData.py
Variables    ../Resources/PageObjects/Login_Dashboard_locators.py
Library       String

*** Keywords ***
Start Browser
    [Arguments]                ${url}
    Set Global Variable  ${testsRootFolder}  ${EXECDIR}

    ${chrome_path}      Catenate   SEPARATOR=      ${EXECDIR}          \\    Drivers     \\       chromedriver.exe

    ${result} =    Replace String    ${chrome_path}    \\    \\\\

    Create Webdriver     ${Browser}   executable_path=${result}
    ${driver}=      Go To    ${url}

    Set Global Variable        ${driver}
    Maximize Browser Window
```